# Browser can't access css file

Tags: css

I keep encountering the same problem with each (infrequent) time that I do any web development. The browser is unable to find my stylesheet.

The file, "style.css", is in EXACTLY THE SAME directory as the .htm file which references it as

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css" type = "text/css" media = "screen" />
```

The script has been cut and pasted from a working web site which I built in the past. That still works perfectly. I have checked my typing carefully at both ends. It is illogical to the point of frustration!

Is there any way in which I can check which directory and what file the browser is looking in?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use meta tag `<base href="http://www.yoursite.com/root/"/>` and then use relative path for the stylesheets. Also check whether you are giving proper permissions  for the css files

Comment: What's the URL? Is it a local server or a `file:`?

Comment: is style.css the correct path? - @POD

Comment: Do you use a CMS? If yes which one? What about the images: are they loading fine?

Comment: Provide screenshots or a link, or paste your entire code?

Answer (score 2):

try to remove extra spaces , like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try that, but to no avail. I copied in an external stylesheet from another site which I built some time ago, and I changed the file directory of my current project to be parallel with the other. The other works perfectly while my current one can't be found. It is very strange.

Comment: @POD may be you have a `base` tag in `head` ?

Comment: I just tried to ADD a base tag, but that had no effect either. Good thinking.

Comment: @POD try to give it absolute path , like `href="http://www.myabsolute.path/style.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Put a forward-slash before your URL, this happens to me sometimes using Visual Studio.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Tried, but no change. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input.

It turned out that the browser was indeed finding the file, but wasn't rendering any of the style because I had some incomplete Javascript which which was clearing everything that might have been rendered. As such, I was getting a blank screen each time.

This was only brought to my attention when I tried to do inline CSS, and that didn't render either. I then noticed that the file preview was displaying a background that I temporarily inserted.